# Custom Rectangle defined in XAML

Tags: silverlight

I have a bit of a strange question and need. Basically, I need a rectangle control that can have a different border thickness **and** different color `stroke` for each of the four sides (and all stroke values, such as dash, etc.). The `Border` control gets me half way there allowing for different thickness values for each side of the rectangle, but doesn't allow for a different color brush for each of the sides.

I've tried using a standard `Canvas` and snapping `Line` to each of the sides, but they don't snap based on `HorizontalAlighnment` or `VerticalAlignment` - a certain number of absolute position attributes are required.

I'll know the width of my rectangle, but not it's height - meaning the vertical sides of the rectangle need to be dynamically sized.

Any thoughts on how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the Canvas. Snapping and alignment have no effect on the children of a Canvas. It only supports absolute positioning of its child elements.

You can define a polygon* with 4 segments, each named so you can access its properties, and apply your settings to each. Polygons *will* stretch shape to fit containers (like a grid) but will not distort the stroke width.

Best to create a user-control wrapping all the above and expose the 4 strokes and colours as Dependency properties so you can bind them.

*Note: It is much easier to author with Expression Blend, but I realise a lot of people do not have it, so will add example Xaml later when I get back to my own PC.*

Comment: Interesting idea! I'm going to try this out today, I'll let you know the results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could build a 3x3 Grid :

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

And set the bottom stroke of 2, the right stroke of 4, the left stroke of 6 and the top stroke of 8 using different colors. The rectangle content would be in cell 5.

Comment: This is an option I've considered, but I can't get the `Line` element to stretch across 1-2-3, 7-8-9, 1-4-7 or 3-6-9. Any thoughts on how that could be done?